# Div gets into wrong position

Tags: html, model-view-controller, position

```
<div>
        <div style="width:100%;">
            <div style="float:left;width:25%;height:100%;">
                <h1>XP: 15795</h1>
                <h1>Nivel: 15</h1>
            </div>
            <div style="width:50%">
                <h1>Image</h1>
            </div>
            <div style="float:right;width:25%">
                <h1 align="right">523<img src="http://i.imgur.com/1hw2bog.png" height="100%" width="72px"/></h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is the code I have to create the div, and on the picture below is what I see from the MVC editor. Thanks in advance
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mn6b6.png

Answer (score 1):

Changed place of the div and worked code was:

```
<div style="width:100%;">
        <div style="float:left;width:25%;">
            <h1>XP: 15795</h1>
            <h1>Nivel: 15</h1>
        </div>
         <div style="float:right;width:25%;">
            <h1 align="right">523<img src="http://i.imgur.com/1hw2bog.png" height="100%" width="72px"/></h1>
        </div>
        <div style="width:50%;">
            <h1>Image</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for the size of the whole element. Remember that the size is the sum of the margins, paddings and the actual size of the element inside. The div gets into that position because is getting pushed by the other elements margin.

You can add a container to hold all the elements on the top, and add it a `display: inline;` to make them stack in the same line. Then position the "Nivel: 15" block with relative positioning.

```
<div>
    <div style="display: inline-block;">
        <div style="float: left;"><h1>XP: 15795</h1></div>
        <div style="float: left;"><h1>Image</h1></div>
    </div>
    <div style="float: right;">
        <h1>523<img src="http://i.imgur.com/1hw2bog.png" height="100%" width="72px"/></h1>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;">
        <div><h1>Nivel: 15</h1></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This structure should help you to make such a layout (I would also recommend lowering the size of the image since that is also what's increasing the height of the div)

Comment: The size of the whole element gets all of it, I'm going to test adding a container

Comment: Fixed it by changing the place of the div